# Replace values multiple columns

Tags: r, replace

I have a data table "data" with 25 columns. In some of the columns (about 15), **which contain numeric values** (but defined as characters after import), I want to replace certain characters, f.e. "," by ".", "<" by "", ">" by "" etc. (could be 10 or more combinations), because some values are like this "<0,17" or "> 1,5".

As the column names change (because it affects different data tables) I would like to solve it this way (it's not correct what I code, it's just to show, what I want to do).

```
replace <- list ("," = ".", "<" = "", ">" = "")
affectedColumns = c("name1", "name2", "name3" ... "name 14", "name 15").

mydata %>%
  mutate(affectedColumns, replace)
```

Another problem is, that some of the columns are numeric and some of them are characters. Does it make sense to first convert all values in "affectedColumns" to to characters (as.character) > then do the replacement process and then convert all of them back to numeric (as.numeric)?

**In the end I would like to have values with "." as comma and without any "<" or ">" or blank spaces.**

Is there a way to do that?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(mydata)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(mydata))`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R way.

```
mydata[affectedColumns] <- lapply(mydata[affectedColumns], \(x){
  for(nm in names(replace)) x <- sub(nm, replace[nm], x)
  as.numeric(x)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
  # Step 1: remove < and >:
  mutate(across(c(everything()), 
                ~ sub("\\s?(>|<)", "", .))) %>%
  # Step 2: replace dot by comma:
  mutate(across(c(everything()), 
                ~ sub("\\.", ",", .))) 
  col1   col2
1  1,2 12,701
2    3  55,77
3    5   5000
```

**EDIT**:

Here's a solution with `setNames` and `stringr`:

First define your sets of new and old values (make sure to escape regex metacharacters such as the `.`):

```
replacements <- setNames(c("", "", ","),     # new values
                         c("<", ">", "\\.")) # old values
```

or, more economically:

```
replacements <- setNames(c("", ","),      # new values
                         c("<|>", "\\.")) # old values
```

Now use `str_replace_all`to implement the changes in one go:

```
library(stringr)
mydata %>%
  mutate(across(c(col1:col2), 
                ~ str_replace_all(., replacements)))
```

Toy data:

```
mydata <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("1.2", "3", "<5"),
  col2 = c(">12.701", "55,77", "< 5000")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `parse_number` from the `readr` package to convert to numeric while removing larger/less than signs.

```
library(readr)

df <- data.frame("name1" = c("1,5", "> 1,5", "<1,6"), 
                 "name2" = c("1,5", "1,5", "1,5"), 
                 "name3" = c("1,0", "1", "1"),
                 "name4" = c(1.5, 1, 0.5)
                 )

affectedColumns <- c("name1", "name2", "name3")

new_df <- mutate(df, across(affectedColumns, .fns = ~parse_number(.x, locale = locale(decimal_mark = ","))))
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider a combination of the `mutate`, `across` and the `case_when` functions form the `dplyr` package. You can find them here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html and here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html or give a minimal reproducible example.

Best,
M.

Answer (score -1):

```
structure(list(D = c(12327, 12328, 12329, 12330, 12331, 12333, 
12334, 12335, 12336, 12337, 12338, 12339, 12340, 12343, 12345, 
12348, 12349, 12350, 12351, 12352), E = c(12310, 12310, 12326, 
12326, 12315, 12326, 0, 12324, 12324, 12334, 12334, 0, 12339, 
0, 0, 12345, 12345, 0, 12343, 12343), Basiswert = c("AUDCAD", 
"AUDCAD", "USDJPY", "USDJPY", "USDCAD", "USDJPY", "USDCHF", "USDCHF", 
"USDCHF", "USDCHF", "USDCHF", "USDCAD", NA, "USDCAD", "CADJPY", 
"CADJPY", "CADJPY", "USDCHF", "USDCAD", "USDCAD"), Einstieg = c(NA, 
0.89262, NA, 139.192, NA, NA, 0.9052, NA, 0.90834, NA, 0.90816, 
NA, NA, 1.362, 103.188, NA, 102.886, 0.9051, NA, 1.36504), Profit = c(33, 
NA, 34, NA, 68, 68, NA, 33, NA, 33, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 34, NA, 
NA, 33, NA), SL = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.91134, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.3684, 102.545, NA, NA, 0.91138, NA, NA), TP = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.89325, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.3504, 
104.35, NA, NA, 0.8933, NA, NA), Trader = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "Trade by Jason\" ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Trade by Jason\" ", 
"Trade by Jason\" ", NA, NA, "Trade by Jason\" ", NA, NA)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(
    E = c(0, 12310, 12315, 12324, 12326, 12334, 12339, 12343, 
    12345), .rows = structure(list(c(7L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 18L), 
        1:2, 5L, 8:9, c(3L, 4L, 6L), 10:11, 13L, 19:20, 16:17), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -9L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Many thanks for your efforts and solutions. However, I did not work on the entire data set. See the example above.